# emacs font for western and Other like rtl

Tags: emacs, fonts, elisp, persian, emacs24

In office like libreOffice we have two type font in style, western font and CTL font.

all English font use western font and other things like persian and arabic font use CTL font.

[image: libre office example]

in emacs 24 i want western text use this settings

```
 '(default ((t (:stipple nil :background "black" :foreground "chartreuse" :inverse-video nil :box nil :strike-through nil :overline nil :underline nil :slant normal :weight normal :height 96 :width normal :family monaco ))))
```

and all rtl and persian text use some thing diffrent.

how can this be happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a simple way to use another font for a range of character, for example for Arabic sub set.
use this in your init file :

```
(set-fontset-font
   "fontset-default"
   (cons (decode-char 'ucs #x0600) (decode-char 'ucs #x06ff)) ; arabic
   "DejaVu Sans Mono")
```

See [Modifying Fontsets](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Modifying-Fontsets.html)

Comment: Can we specify a different font size as well? I want my Arabic text to be bigger.

Comment: I found the answer: `(setq face-font-rescale-alist '(("Cordia New" . 1.20)))`

Comment: Hey @fzeroubigd, I encounter this error with this config:

Loading /home/milad/.spacemacs...done
(Spacemacs) Error in dotspacemacs/init: Wrong type argument: symbolp, (set-fontset-font "fontset-default" (cons (decode-char (quote ucs) 1536) (decode-char (quote ucs) 1791)) "Vazir")